# Ansible set hostname, username and password in playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a ansible play book to run a command on remote host.

Is it possible to write a `host_ip`, `username` and `password` with in play book?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far and then explain how that isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the hostname if the inventory file under a group like that:

```
[group-name]
34.67.12.12
```

and then in the playbook yml you can specify a group to run on like that:

```
- hosts: group-name
  gather_facts: true
  sudo: yes
  vars_files:
    - "group_vars/group-name/config"
  roles:
    - do-bla-bla
```

about the username and password its is not secure to write it in the variable file , for that there is ansible vault